# answer packages rejected between mangle/prerouting and nat/prerouting

Tags: routing, network, firewall

I am currently configuring a ubiquity edgerouter for our network. We have one uplink port (eth2) and two internal ports (eth0; with vlan 1) and eth3 (with vlans 2,3 and 4).
uplink and vlan 1 have public IPs. vlans 2-4 use internal (192.168.0.0/16) IPs.
All Traffic coming in from vlans 2-4 is NATed to a public IP.
I have zone based firewalling and each vlan + uplink has its own zone.

I have all firewall rules set up so that the hosts in vlan 2-4 can e.g. ping the internet but they can't. The hosts on eth0.1 don't get NATed and they can ping the public internet.

I traced the problem down to the following:
When I tcpdump on eth2 I see the NATed package going out and the reply comming in followed by a ICMP port unreachable send out.
When I add LOG entries into mangle/PREROUTING and nat/PREROUTING I see the reply package come by the End of mangle/PREROUTING but not the beginning of nat/PREROUTING.
I was not able to find out what motivates the kernel to reject the package between these two chains.
I found multiple Variation of the iptables flow (e.g. [on wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Netfilter-packet-flow.svg)) and they all state nothing between these chains.

Can someone tell me what might reject these packages?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

First I did not read the linked image correctly. It clearly states ' “nat” table only consulted   for “NEW” connections'. So that's why I was not seeing the return packages in nat/PREROUTING.

After that I followed the traffic and found that I did forget to add the firewall rules from the uplink zones to the internal zones.

After adding that everything worked fine.

Sorry for the Noise